# Free POP3 mail component

Tags: .net, parsing, email, .net-3.5

Right now I'm working on a project, which will read mails from pop3 inbox and save its attachments to specified folder.

I'm looking for a free POP3 mail component, which can be used with .NET 3.5;

Please recommend easy to use POP3 component, it will be great if it is open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com) is an open source alternative that has its value.

It supports advanced POP3 features and much more.

Answer (score 1):

I have also used OpenPOP.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/